# How to extract django form fields?

Tags: django

I have the following script in **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserLog
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

PC_CHOICES = (
        ("1", "lab0034"),
        ("2", "lab0127"),
        ("3", "lab0128"),
    )

class UserLogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserLog
        fields = [
            'data_location',
            'pc',
            'scenario',
            'description',
        ]
    data_location = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.TextInput)
    pc = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PC_CHOICES)
    scenario = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

I want to use form fields in HTML page(JS code). I have the below code in html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data_location = ' {{ form.data_location }} '
        var pc_index = ' {{ form.pc }} '
        console.log(pc_index);
</script>
```

I'm able to get the index of the pc here. But how to get the value of pc?. For eg., if the index is 1, it should show pc lab0127?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{{ form.get_pc_display }}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It looks totally unrelated function but it worked!